# AddForce doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this following code in a FixedUpdate() method with a Input.GetMouseButton(0) condition:

```
public void playerAttack()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(player.transform.position, player.transform.forward, out hit, range)) //range = 7f
    {
        if (hit.rigidbody != null && hit.transform.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            Vector3 dir = new Vector3(hit.transform.position.x, hit.transform.position.y, hit.transform.position.z - 100f);
            hit.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(dir * weaponPush * Time.deltaTime); //weaponPush = 1f
        }
    }

}
```

The enemy object has rigidbody on it and isKinematic is not selected. It still doesn't move when I am almost in front of it and click the left mouse button.

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint anywhere? Does it go inside the second `if`?

Comment: Yes, it enters the second if. But the enemy object doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This not working could be because of many things:

- your **Rigidbody** could be set to [Kinematic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html)
- your **Rigidbody** [drag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-drag.html) value could be too high
- your object could move but you don't see it because force is to low (may be cause of the use of `Time.deltaTime`)
- if your object is located in `[0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f]`, the `dir` vector will be `Vector3.zero`

Also as a side note I'd advise using `Time.fixedDeltaTime` inside `FixedUpdate()` (`Time.deltaTime` will return the same value but this way you remember working inside a "physics" frame).

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: Thanks man, the problem was `Time.deltaTime`. It reduced the force so it was not even seeable. I don't know why I even add it.